# SVG unit system is different than expected

Tags: reactjs, svg

In the screenshot of the DOM you can see that the text ending in the numbers `623` is given a `x` value of `160`. However, when I inspect the text, `something something` which is rendered before the numbers it has a length of `126.08px` (see the second screenshot). This means that my text, which I translated `160px` to the right, is not actually `160px` to the right. From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions), I understand that unless a viewport is provided one user unit should equal one screen unit, but this is obviously not the case here. Why is this? Thanks! I'm using React if that is necessary.
[image: Screen shot of dom]

[image: Screen shot of result]

Comment: What happens if you use set text-anchor to "start"? IIRC setting it to end will shift text to the left with everything else defaulted.

Comment: Unrelated, but please post code as text, not images of text.

Comment: Yea normally I do I do post it as text, but the component is written in a way that it would be way too long. Although, text-anchor did the trick! You're the man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting "text-anchor' to "end' which will end up shifting the text to the left. Set it to 'start' (or possibly skip it altogether) and you should see the behavior you expect.